# Where to write Access-Control-Allow-Origin: or Origin in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cross-domain

So I came to know by searching that I need to set my Access-Control-Allow-Origin: or Origin tags. But where?? Suggestions were to use these in header.

I can't see find anything that explained this. Can anyone please tell me where to put this tags and how!!

Comment: in the header sent by the server (so, nothing to do with javascript or jqueeery)

Comment: ok then where to i write your suggestion. ? @Jaromanda

Comment: in your php - can't give you a better answer because you've shown nothing, sorry ... hint ... `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` hint 2: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=php%20cors%20heaaders&gws_rd=ssl#q=php+Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: i sent to one request in ajax from http://www.exam13.com to http://www.ex12333.com that time i face the error message `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource a.......`

Comment: You cant change other peoples server to let you in

Comment: Which web server are you using (apache, nginx, ..) ?  can you edit the configuration of this server or a .htaccess file ?

Comment: @yoann .. i am using apache

Comment: @Yoann - why would he need CORS on his own server?

Comment: @Ambal - are you the owner of the server you want to contact with your ajax request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **PHP** file * I guess you have ajax request, etc.*

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *'); 

...
```

Comment: request file at least. You should put it in BOTH. See my EDIT/update. Have fun coding. If ok, please accept my answer.

Comment: There is more to CORS implementation than simply adding one header

Comment: I think @AmbalMani does not want to be a CORS expert, but he wants to make its app working... header putting like in this example is far ok. Unless you work for a very big firm, isnt it ?

Comment: @3pic not if you don't account for preflight `OPTIONS` requests. Both of these answers oversimplify the issue

Comment: @AmbalMani please accept my answer if it is working for you - i m sure of. I have developped loooots of ajax requests with it , working like a charm.  BTW you should process asking and results in the same php, seems more efficient for your productivity .... cheers

Answer (score 0):

in the header sent by the server (so, nothing to do with javascript or jqueeery)

and the correct answer is thanks to @Jaromanda X .

```
 <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *'); ?>
```

in top line